# Reading xmlnode child tag value

Tags: c#, xmlnode

My xml file looks like below.

```xml
<mappings>
  <mapping>
    <a>a1value</a>
    <b>
      <c>
        <d>d1value</d>
        <e>e1value</e>
      </c>
    </b>
  </mapping>
  <mapping>
    <a>a2value</a>
    <b>
      <c>
        <d>d2value</d>
        <e>e2value</e>
      </c>
    </b>
  </mapping>
</mappings>
```

C# code to read the value of a,d tags.

```cs
XmlDocument xmlDocNew = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement CATLOG = xmlDocNew.CreateElement("mappings");
XmlNode xmlNodeTab = xmltest.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList xmlNodeListCD = xmlNodeTab.SelectNodes("//mapping");
foreach (XmlNode xmlNodeCD in xmlNodeListCD)
{
   string innerText = xmlNodeCD["a"].InnerText;
   string xmlNodeapp = xmlNodeCD["//b/c/d"].InnerText;
}
```

With the above code i am able to iterate through all the "a" tag elements.
But I am not able to read "d" tag value.
How do I read the value of "d" tag?

When I iterate through each element in the `foreach` loop, I want to get the value of "a" tag and its corresponding "d" tag value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks at each of the mapping and under it, looks up the value for tags `a` and `d`. Also note that if you want to look up 'sub' tags and only get these child items, you have to use `.//` instead of just `//`. Dot notation pulls node "under" the current node.

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load($@"{Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName}\json.txt");

    var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//mapping");
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        var aNodes = node.SelectNodes(".//a");
        foreach (XmlNode aNode in aNodes)
            Console.WriteLine(aNode.InnerText);

        // If you know there will only be one node at .//b/c/d, use SelectSingleNode instead.
        Console.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode(".//b/c/d").InnerText);
    }
```

**Output**

```
a1value
d1value
a2value
d2value
```

**Note:**

`a` tag is sort of a sibling of `d` tag and their singular parent is the `mapping` element. You would get best results if you got all the mapping nodes and then worked through those.

Comment: in each iteration i want to read "a" tag value and its corresponding "d" value. With the above code i only get the value of "d" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Since .Net 3.5 there is Linq and Linq To XML which makes XML parsing easier. With Linq To XML you could read it as:

```
    void Main()
    {
        var s = @"<mappings>
      <mapping>
        <a>a1value</a>
        <b>
          <c>
            <d>d1value</d>
            <e>e1value</e>
          </c>
        </b>
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <a>a2value</a>
        <b>
          <c>
            <d>d2value</d>
            <e>e2value</e>
          </c>
        </b>
      </mapping>
    </mappings>";
        var data = from x in XDocument.Parse(s).Descendants("mapping")
                   select new {
                    a=(string)x.Element("a"),
                    d=(string)x.Element("b").Element("c").Element("d")
                    };

        foreach (var e in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{e.a}, {e.d}");
        }
    }
```

With a file, instead of `.Parse`, you would use `.Load( filename )`.

**Output**:

```
a1value, d1value
a2value, d2value
```

If you have a class matching this structure, like:

```
public class MyData
{ 
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
}
```

Then instead of the anonymous type you could use this class like so:

```
var data = from x in XDocument.Parse(s).Descendants("mapping")
           select new MyData {
            A=(string)x.Element("a"),
            D=(string)x.Element("b").Element("c").Element("d")
            };

foreach (var e in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{e.A}, {e.D}");
}
```

PS: Since you are getting an IEnumerable, you could directly bind data to a `DataGridView, ListBox ... ( ...DataSource = data.ToList())`.